# Why are there differences in docker pull and docker build in IBM Container Service?

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

We're using the IBM Container Service on Bluemix and have discovered an oddity that we can't quite explain -- it seems that docker pull and docker build act differently with regard to authentication.

First, the obligatory version information:

```
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.7.0, build 0baf609
$ ice version
ICE CLI Version        : 3.0 598 2015-07-02T19:39:30
$ cf -v
cf version 6.12.1-56792aa-2015-07-06T22:48:00+00:00
```

This is a brand new Ubuntu VM with only docker, ice (and it's prereqs) and the cf tools installed on it.  I built a simple little Node example to show the problem.  Just create this app.js and Dockerfile and put them in a directory somewhere (I used Dev/node-hello) then cd to the directory.

app.js

```
var http = require('http');
var appport = 9085;
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
res.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(appport);
console.log("Server running at port");
console.log(appport);
```

Dockerfile

```
# sample dockerfile for demonstration
FROM registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode:latest
RUN apt-get -y update
ADD app.js /app.js
EXPOSE 9085
CMD  ["node", "app.js"]
```

Now, after doing a ice login, which logs you into the cf tools as well, try the following:

`sudo docker build -t <your_namespace>/node-hello`

The docker build will die with the last line being:

Authentication is required.

That's not very helpful, so if you restart the docker daemon in debug mode using:

`sudo /usr/bin/docker -d -D &`

And then rerun the build, you'll find that docker had encountered some errors prior to putting out the authentication error:

`DEBU[2494] Error unmarshalling the _ping RegistryInfo: invalid character 'U' after top-level value`

Which may be related or may be a red herring.

Now, the odd part is that if you then do a:

`sudo docker pull registry.ng.bluemix.net/ibmnode`

It will pull the image locally without a problem, and then if you issue your docker build command again, it will run fine!  Are we just using docker build incorrectly somehow (I don't think so...this always worked before...) or is there an odd difference between the way pulls and builds are managed?

Comment: What is your question, is unclear what your question is?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem locally on my Mac and was not able to reproduce the problem.  Do you think it is Linux specific?

Comment: It was not Linux specific as of last week when this was posted - another one of our folks managed to reproduce it following the exact sequence of steps outlined above on the Mac as well.

Comment: Ryan, I just validated that it still happens on Linux.  I removed all the local images in my docker, did the docker build as above, and encountered the authentication error again.

Comment: Now that I'm digging into different documentation sources, it appears that the behavior of Dockerfile FROM may be ambiguous.  The digital ocean "docker explained" site, states that FROM should have the following behavior: "If a FROM image is not found on the host, docker will try to find it (and download) from the docker image index. " The official docker documentation, on the other hand, only states the following: "The image can be any valid image – it is especially easy to start by pulling an image from the Public Repositories."  So what SHOULD the behavior be?

Comment: Jeff, I think the question was pretty clear - HOW is this supposed to work and why are they acting differently?  Isn't FROM supposed to do a pull automatically from a linked docker repository if you don't have the image already downloaded locally (lots of online examples and the DigitalOcean tutorial all indicate that this should be true...)

Comment: Ryan, one thing that's important - this only happens in a BRAND NEW docker install - if you already have the image in your local cache, it doesn't occur.  So when trying to reproduce it, either delete that specific image from your local cache, or start from a new VM with docker installed.

Comment: @KyleGeneBrown are you still having issues with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be due to a [known bug](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/14092) in Docker. It looks like they have [issued a fix](https://github.com/docker/docker/pull/14139) in 1.7.1.

Can you upgrade your client and try again?

Comment: For what it's worth I was just told that Docker 1.7.x is not currently supported by [IBM Containers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31416811/851145).