# bluemix "docker images" results in "json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int"

Tags: docker, ibm-cloud

I have successfully uploaded two images from the docker registry to my IBM Bluemix registry, which I can see when logging into the Bluemix UI.  However, I am unable to list the images using the CLIs.

Using the docker command I receive the following:

```
krsyoung:code krsyoung$ docker images
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int
```

And with cf ic:

```
krsyoung:code krsyoung$ cf ic images
json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type int

Invalid IBM-Containers commands or docker commands.
Available IBM Containers commands are {login, group, ip, route,     volume, namespace, info}
In addition, IBM Containers supports native docker cli passthrough, run cf ic help for more details
```

Here are the versions of software I'm running:

```
krsyoung:code krsyoung$ docker --version
Docker version 1.7.0, build 0baf609

krsyoung:code krsyoung$ cf --version
cf version 6.12.0-8c65bbd-2015-06-30T00:05:01+00:00

krsyoung:code krsyoung$ cf plugins
Listing Installed Plugins...
OK

Plugin Name      Version   Command Name   Command Help   
IBM-Containers   0.8.598   ic             IBM-Containers Plugin
```

Adding the debug flag does not help.  Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using Docker 1.6.2 or 1.7?

Comment: @RamVennam I'm using 1.7.  I've updated the original post with additional version information.

Answer (score 1):

Please use docker 1.6.2. Docker 1.7 isn't supported at the moment

Comment: Curious, would this explain why the `cf ic images` command does not work?

Comment: Apparently the answer is yes.  I downgraded to Docker 1.6.2 and the command is working now.  @RamVennam any chance there is an ETA posted on IBM Containers supporting 1.7.x?

Comment: Just for the record IBM Containers as caught up now.  Currently using `Docker version 1.10.0, build 590d5108` without any issues!